# Match UserProperty() with StringProperty()

Tags: python

I want to match `StringProperty()` with `UserProperty` and I can't change property so how can I achieve it? Please help me out.

Comment: We will need more information to be able to help you...

Comment: We don't know what StringProperty and UserProperty are. Python itself doesn't have those.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be talking about Google App Engine's model properties. To the best of my knowledge, you can't query a UserProperty with a string, because a User is not a string. Instead, try creating a brand new [User object](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/userclass.html); you just need the email address of the user. Then you can query for users matching that user.